# Passing Jacobian to Julia through the diffeqpy python package

Tags: python, julia, differentialequations.jl

I have a Python package that defines an ODE `y'=f(y)` corresponding to the semi-discretisation in space of a heat-like equation.
I want to test some integrators availabe in the `DifferentialEquations` module from Julia, without rewriting everything in Julia, which is a language I do not known very well. Therefore I turned to the `diffeqpy` package that enables the use of these directly in Python.

The PDE I solve is discretised with a few dozens to hundreds cells, and I need to perform lots of simulation for parametric studies, in particular with IMEX methods.
The issue is I cannot find a way to give an hint about the sparsity pattern of the Jacobian of `f` to implicit algorithms. In my current implementation, they just assume it is dense and therefore waste a lot of time computing it by finite-differences without coloring or any similar sparsity-based optimisation...

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. If I have a Python function that generates a (possibly) sparse Jacobian for `f`, how can I plug it in the `diffeqpy` package ?
2. In most cases, my Jacobian is pentadiaognal, or at least its bandwidth is known. Is there any easy way to pass that information to Julia via Python ?

Here is a small example that can serve as a quick test platform for potential solutions:

```py
from julia.api import Julia
jl = Julia(compiled_modules=False)
from diffeqpy import de
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import identity
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


n = 10 # dimension
atol = 1e-7
rtol = 1e-6
tspan = (0., 1.)

u0 = np.linspace(0.1, 10, n)
def f(u,p,t):
    return -2*u

def df(u,p,t):
    # return -2. * np.eye(n)
    return -2. * identity(n)
  


prob = de.ODEProblem(f, u0, tspan) # works
# prob = de.ODEProblem(f, u0, tspan, jac=df) # fails
sol = de.solve(prob, alg=de.RadauIIA5(autodiff=False), abstol=atol, reltol=rtol)

sol2 = solve_ivp(fun=lambda t,y: f(y,None,t),
                 y0=u0, method='Radau', t_span=tspan,
                 atol=atol, rtol=rtol, jac=lambda t,y: df(y,None,t) )

plt.figure()
plt.plot(sol.t,  sol.u, color='tab:red')
plt.plot(sol2.t, sol2.y.T, linestyle='--', linewidth=3, color='tab:blue')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('u')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

**EDIT:**

Passing both `jac` and  `jac_prototype` as suggested works, but only if `jac` is in dense format. Also, how can I only give `jac_prototype` without `jac` ? The latter is not always available in practice, and I was hoping DifferentialEquations would be able to compute it via finite-difference on its own based on the provided sparsity pattern.

Here are the relevant code modifications, with some comments on what works and what does not:

```py
def df(u,p,t):
  return -2. * identity(n, format=form).todense()  #fails without todense()

df_prototype = diags([1], offsets=[0], shape=(n,n), format=form) #.todense()
  
func = de.ODEFunction(f, jac=df, jac_prototype=df_prototype) # works
# func = de.ODEFunction(f, jac_prototype=df_prototype) # fails
prob = de.ODEProblem(func, u0, tspan)
# prob = de.ODEProblem(f, u0, tspan) # works with finte-difference dense jacobian
sol = de.solve(prob, alg=de.RadauIIA5(autodiff=False), abstol=atol, reltol=rtol, verbose=False)
```

If I omit the `jac` argument in the `ODEFunction` line, then the following error is thrown upon calling `de.solve`:

- `JULIA: MethodError: no method matching matrix_colors(::PyObject)` if I use a sparse Jacobian prototype
- `JULIA: MethodError: no method matching findstructralnz(::Matrix{Float64})`
  it I use a todense() to give a dense jacobian prototype

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a Python function that generates a (possibly) sparse Jacobian for f, how can I plug it in the diffeqpy package ?

```
func = de.ODEFunction(f, jac = jac, jac_prototype = sparsejac)
prob = de.ODEProblem(func, u0, tspan)
```

where `sparsejac` is a sparse matrix matching the sparsity of the Jacobian, and `jac(u,p,t)` returns such a Jacobian.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems to work, but only if the actual jacobian is in dense format. Using any sparse format (csc, csr...) leads to an error similar to `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'PyCall.jlwrap' and 'csc_matrix'`.
Also, I was actually hoping I could only pass the sparsity pattern, not a function that computes the Jacobian (since I do not always have such a  function). If I remove the `jac` argument, I get the following error : `JULIA: MethodError: no method matching matrix_colors(::PyObject)`. I have edited my question with my current code.